# custom package with layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, package

I created a custom package **com.test1.web** and I have a class into this package. (Class with activity extends)

My application run with **com.test2.main** source.

I dont have access to **R.layout** in customized package.

How can i do to access this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [RemoveViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) in extension application and send it via intent to main package.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("OPEN_YOUR_MAIN_APP");
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_layout);
        intent.putExtra("layout", views);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Or another approach is to create a context of your extension application in main application, via method [Context#createPackageContext(String, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createPackageContext(java.lang.String,%20int))
and invoke [Context#getResources()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources())

```
    try {
        Context extensionAppContext = context.createPackageContext("com.test1.web", Context.CONTEXT_RESTRICTED);
        Resources extensionAppResources = extensionAppContext.getResources();
        int layoutId = extensionAppResources.getIdentifier("layout_name", "layout", "com.test1.web");
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but I cant use that... my app running in com.test2.main .  and in main layout, i used <com.test1.web...... /> to show that.

Comment: looks like i don't understand you at first, so you can create a library module with your layouts, and share it among two applications

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want to export it to library :) but i don't know how I can use layout :(

Comment: you need to create the library, and use it in both applications, that's all. Or can you add some more explanation of your intent